# Hibernate envers one-to-one relationship not both side audited

Tags: java, orm, mapping, one-to-one, hibernate-envers

I am using 4.3.6 hibernate and envers.

I have 2 entity A and B. A is the main entity and B is a sub-section of A.

They are one-to-one and bi-directional.

Both of them are @Audited, there are 3 scenario happens when I save A:

1. Save A, both A and B is modified. There will be a new Revision Number shared by both.
2. Save A, only A is modified. There will be a new Revision for A.
3. Save A, only B is modified. There will be a new Revision for B.   (I don't want this)

I will always save Entity A and cascade B to update. How can I have the revision for entity A in scenario 3? Many thanks!!!

for data schema, my schema is configured according to the answer of this post:
My data schema:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class B implements Serializable {

    ....

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to A
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="b", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    private A a;

    }

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name="A")
public class A implements Serializable {

...

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to B
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private B b;
```

When I save persist entity A ( A is not modified and B is modified),

```
Hibernate generated sql

Hibernate: update A set ...

Hibernate: update B set ...

Hibernate: update C set ...

Hibernate: insert into RevEntity (CREATE_DATE, timestamp, username, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into B_AUD ...
```

Comment: Can you post your actual data schema by editing your question ? Any relevant code will help SO members to better answer your question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to force Envers to also modify `A` when you modify `B` directly.  You'd have to trigger that requirement in your business/persistence code to alter a value on `A` so that it is included in the revision for your use case.